# Getting click events from SlickGrid buttons

Tags: jquery, events, slickgrid

I'm building a `SlickGrid` using data from php acquired at run-time. There will be an arbitrary number so I'm using one **class** designation and giving each button a unique **id** based on the data as I loop through it.

What I don't seem to be figuring out is how to get the **click** event from each button and distinguish which button the event came from.

My `SlickGrid` columns are defined as follows:

```
columns.push(
{id: "Service", name: "Service", field: "svcname", sortable: true},
{id: "active", name: "Running", sortable: false, width: 50, 
    cssClass: "cell-pid", field: "pid", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkmark },
{id: "toggle", name: "", width: 50, formatter: togglebuttonFormatter}
);
```

With the buttons formatted as:

```
    function togglebuttonFormatter( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext )
    {
        var button;

        // running or not?
       if( dataContext.pid != null )
         button = "<center><input class='toggleStop' type='button' id='" + dataContext.svcname + "' value='Stop'></center>";
       else
         button = "<center><input class='toggleStart' type='button' id='" + dataContext.svcname + "' value='Start'></center>";
       return button;
    }
```

I've been trying to get the **click** event using a variety of

```
$( <selector> ).click( function() { ... } );
```

to no avail. I've used chrome to find the specific class#id combination (and tried regex for the class) for each button but I'm missing some important step. Suggestions?

Comment: which selectors have you tried?  did you try '.toggleStop'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because the buttons are added dynamically by SlickGrid...

You might want to try something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggleStart', function() { });
```

Comment: This works great. You can use `this.id` to figure out which button was pushed.

Comment: Any idea why this works? I had the same problem, and it seems like appending the click handler to the `body` instead of the `input` element itself did the trick. My problem was that I could handle the click event, but any time the user scrolled past a certain number of rows, the events would no longer register.